# crossprod by factor of vectors in a data.table

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

I have a `data.table` dists which looks like this:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1800 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ groupname: Factor w/ 8 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ start    : int  0 60 120 180 240 300 360 420 480 540 ...
 $ V1       : num  1041 955 962 865 944 ...
 $ vN       : num  0.0042 0.00385 0.00388 0.00349 0.00381 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Here's a `dput` of the whole thing: http://pastebin.com/VW54NfUg

I can do each crossprod of vN by factor individually. e.g.

```
crossprod(as.matrix(dists[c(groupname=="C")]$vN), 
          as.matrix(dists[c(groupname=="D")]$vN))
```

But I'd like to do them all at once and output them as a matrix that looks something like this:

```
            C           D           E           F           G           H
C 0.000000000                                               
D 0.003515663 0.000000000                            
E 0.003530643 0.003580947 0.000000000          
F 0.003580947 0.003409901 0.003522218 0.000000000          
G 0.003522218 0.003515663 0.003409901 0.003580947 0.000000000 
H 0.003409901 0.003522218 0.003515663 0.003530643 0.003515663  0.000000000
```

I have a feeling this is probably really straightforward, but I'm new to working with `data.table` and matrices. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you're just describing a matrix multiplication X'X, where the columns of X are the vN values and you have one column for each group. You can use the split-apply-combine paradigm to compute X:

```
# Get rid of stray labels
dists$groupname <- as.character(dists$groupname)

# Define X matrix and compute final table
X <- do.call(cbind, lapply(split(dists, dists$groupname), function(x) x$vN))
(cp <- t(X) %*% X)
#             C           D           E           F           G           H
# C 0.003495762 0.003515663 0.003530643 0.003580947 0.003522218 0.003409901
# D 0.003515663 0.003720479 0.003677919 0.003757778 0.003650462 0.003477723
# E 0.003530643 0.003677919 0.003750939 0.003784916 0.003665951 0.003485093
# F 0.003580947 0.003757778 0.003784916 0.003994177 0.003775697 0.003526653
# G 0.003522218 0.003650462 0.003665951 0.003775697 0.003740864 0.003476628
# H 0.003409901 0.003477723 0.003485093 0.003526653 0.003476628 0.003438210
```

If you wanted 0 down the main diagonal, you could finish with `diag(cp) <- 0`.

Answer (score 3):

As @josilber points out, this is simple matrix multiplication, you just have to extract the matrix. Here's a simpler and faster way of extracting it:

```
setkey(dists, groupname) # making sure it's ordered by groupname

X = dists[, matrix(vN, ncol = length(unique(groupname)))]
colnames(X) = unique(dists$groupname)

crossprod(X, X)
#            C           D           E           F           G           H
#C 0.003495762 0.003515663 0.003530643 0.003580947 0.003522218 0.003409901
#D 0.003515663 0.003720479 0.003677919 0.003757778 0.003650462 0.003477723
#E 0.003530643 0.003677919 0.003750939 0.003784916 0.003665951 0.003485093
#F 0.003580947 0.003757778 0.003784916 0.003994177 0.003775697 0.003526653
#G 0.003522218 0.003650462 0.003665951 0.003775697 0.003740864 0.003476628
#H 0.003409901 0.003477723 0.003485093 0.003526653 0.003476628 0.003438210
```